# Slow import prestashop DB tables when filled

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

Why does during csv prestashop import products/combinations it slow down until it stops responding as the tables are filled in the database?
If I empty the tables, the import returns to be fluid and smoothly until they fill up again (around 30 megabytes) and thousand rows.

[image: "filled" tables around 30 mbyte]

Comment: You've circled something on an image with illegible text.

Comment: You can click on image and enlarge

Comment: How about posting the relevant information, which appears to be just a tiny bit of plain text, **as a tiny bit of plain text**?

Comment: what informations ?

Answer (score 0):

Built-in import functionality in PrestaShop doesn't work very well when trying to process large amount of data. When processing every next entry, import script is (probably) recalculating all existing data in some way, so the process becomes slower and slower.

The only way to quickly import your data is to use a custom script that will insert entries **directly** to the database. You can write it by yourself or you can use some third-party proprietary software for shop management.